# Is there a way to automate field calculations for ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, field-calculator, feature-service

I have a field that I'd like to be concatenated with each new objectID when a feature is created in my feature service.

Workflow:

- Feature added, already contains objectID.
- Would like my Service Request field to be updated also on the DB side.
  Service number = SRS + ObjectID = ex. SRS2012

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a hassle but you could write a Feature Class extension in the geodatabase. In the create event you just update the Service number field.

Read more on feature class extensions:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualHelp/#/Creating_class_extensions/000100000201000000/

I don't say it is the only way, but it is very reliable and will ensure that you can't create features without a correct Service number. The major drawbacks are that the extension class (COM) must be installed on all computers that will use the feature class and it requires some ArcObjects programming.

Answer (score 1):

A database trigger should be able to accomplish this. There is a thread in the ESRI forums that discusses using SQL Server triggers with versioned databases:

https://community.esri.com/thread/113402